# In Ruby - what are encodings?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

I'm trying to understand what encodings in Ruby are - there are lots of articles about encodings, such as [this one](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings) and [this one](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/). However, none of them explain the basic question a newbie might have - what *is* an encoding in the first place?

Comment: Not just in Ruby, but in general?

Comment: Yes, in general is fine. I was not sure whether this was a Ruby-specific feature or not.

Comment: Actually J.E. Gray II _does_ explain it, in [the first article](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/what_is_a_character_encoding). Well written and not Ruby specific. You're linking to the ninth article, skipping eight.

Answer (score 5):

What is meant by character encoding here is a system of describing how computers represent characters in binary.

In UTF-8 encoding, the character `ä` is represented as `1100 0011 1010 0100`, or `0xC3 0xA4` in hexadecimal.

In Windows-1252 encoding, the same character is represented as `1110 0100` or `0xE4` in hexadecimal.

So let's say you tell a computer to read a file in Windows-1252, but the file is actually encoded as UTF-8. The file contains just one character, say `ä`. Since the file is in UTF-8, the file actually contains the bits `0xC3 0xA4`. Now because you told (implicitly or explicitly) the computer to read the file in Windows-1252, you will actually see `Ã¤` instead of `ä`.

Answer (score 4):

An encoding is a means of transforming some sequence of bytes into text. [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is one where there's a single byte per character. [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is another common one that uses a variable number of bytes to encode a somewhat larger set of characters. And, of course, [Character Encoding on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) is probably a helpful read.